# How to comment out local variables eval properties in Emacs org files?

Tags: emacs, comments, org-mode

I have this in some of me org files at the end of the file:

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "Arial" :height 130))
# eval: (buffer-face-mode t)
# End:
```

But I want to comment it out so the Arial font is not set, however without deleting it from the file itself - so I can use it later, or go back to Arial, add some other stuff, etc.

I have tried:

```
#+BEGIN_COMMENT
# Local Variables:
# eval: (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "Arial" :height 130))
# eval: (buffer-face-mode t)
# End:
#+END_COMMENT
```

also

```
#Local Variables:
#eval: (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "Arial" :height 130))
#eval: (buffer-face-mode t)
#End:
```

But it still being evaluated.

I have to delete it completely from the file so Arial is not set in that file.

Any way how to comment it out?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest commenting out the line with `;` (the Emacs Lisp comment character) but that does not work. A little trial-and-error later however shows that this would work:

```el
# Local Variables:
# eval: ();; (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "Arial" :height 130))
# eval: (buffer-face-mode t)
# End:
```

The empty parens give `eval` something to do (namely nothing, but it's enough so that the `eval` does not barf), and the `;;` comment out the rest of it. BTW, a single `;` is enough: I added two for visibility.

Comment: Did you try this? Did it work for you?